# Run a scheduled process every day at a certain time on web service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I've been building a web service to synchronize data between SalesForce and Zendesk at my company. In the process of doing so, I've built several optimizations to drastically reduce execution time, such as caching some of the larger datasets that are retrieved from each service.

However, this comes at a price. When caching the data, it can upwards to 3-5 minutes to download everything through SalesForce and Zendesk's APIs.

To combat this, I was thinking of having a background worker that automatically cached all the required data every day a midnight. However, I'm not sure what the best method of doing this would be.

Would it suffice to build a class that merely has a worker thread that checks every several minutes to see if it is after midnight, and activate it on launch from Global.asax. Or is there some sort of scheduler already in existence?

**EDIT**

There seems to be some division between using something like:

[FluentScheduler](https://github.com/jgeurts/FluentScheduler) or [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) to house everything within my applications.

Versus using something like windows task scheduler and writing a secondary application to call a function of my application to do so. It seems that using a third party library would be more *simple*, but is there any inherent benefit to using the Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Windows has a built in task scheduler, use that!

Comment: Would it really be advised to use task scheduler? This seems like something that would be much more simple to have as a background thread within my application. Essentially only a single call is necessary to reset my cache `CacheTools.PopulateCache()`. All that's necessary is that to be called everyday, once a day at a certain time.

Comment: There are multiple scheduling frameworks available, e.g. [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

Comment: @Jdsfighter you can't be sure that your application is running... it it's a web app, believe me, it will be eventually recycled...

Comment: Can you briefly explain recycling for me? Does it simply restart my application? If that's the case, it's setup to automatically fetch data on restart anyways.

Comment: I don't think it is any less simple to use Task Scheduler, if you go that route your caching code is basically just a script and you hand windows responsibility for running the script once a day. If anything that should mean simpler code than using a library within code to handle the scheduling. Either could be used to produce a robust mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to add your data caching logic to a project of type "console application". You'll be able to deploy this to your server and run it as a scheduled task using windows "Task Scheduler". If you've not worked with this project type or scheduled tasks before there are stack overflow questions which should help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739396/schedule-a-c-sharp-console-application), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/187370/what-is-the-best-way-to-run-a-console-application-once-per-day-at-a-certain-time), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007381/console-app-scheduled-task-run-two-different-ways). You can add command line parameters if you need and you should have a look at adding a mutex so that only one instance of your code will ever run at once.

Comment: What would the benefit of that be, over say something like [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/jgeurts/FluentScheduler) which allows me to house everything from within a single web service?

Comment: You could do it either way but I prefer the Task Scheduler, you can easily see the last time the task was run, how long it ran for and when it's next due to run as well as setting off an ad hoc run of the process from windows, you'd have to build that functionality yourself if you just ran your data caching job as a windows service.

Answer (score 0):

add an endpoint that will know how do it and use the windows task scheduler to call that new caching endpoint.